# How can i make a role-required command and a non role-required command in 1 python script?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

So i want to have a script that if i say '$hello' in the Discord server, the bot replies (i want this command to be available for everyone). I also want to have a command in that same script that requires a role or owner, this is my shutdown command, i dont want it to be available for the other members :) could someone please help me? Thank you for reading! my current text is

```py
import time
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands.core import has_permissions

@client.commands()
@commands.is_owner()
async def shutdown(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Logging Out...")
    client.logout()
    print("Exit")
```

this is what i have now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it on `@client.command` instead of `@client.event`. this is more efficient than doing `on_message`

before copy and pasting the command, you should put these on the `client` first

on `client` :

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")
```

The shutdown command :

```py
@client.command()                     # the decorator
@commands.is_owner()                  # it will check if you (the owner of the bot) runs the bot, 
async def shutdown(ctx):              # your command name
    await ctx.send("Shutting down!")  # send the message
    await client.close()              # shuts down the bot
```

Thank me later :D

Comment: it did work for me tho. Did you add the command prefix yet?

Comment: Yes i did, i will copy my whole script (without key) later today

Comment: alright, just wanted to say, did the command output any traceback or not?

Comment: No he did nothing

Comment: Sorry i forgot to do it, i will do it tomorrow if i have time.

Comment: And i asked help in a discord server, they said that too almost the same and that didn’t work either, i dont know whats wrong… someone will copy it and run it later.

Comment: I edited it, this is what i have now: 
```python
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def shutdown(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Logging Out...")
    client.logout()
    print("Exit")

```

Comment: And it still doesn’t do anything… i will execute it on a different website the next time